# Mapbox.xcframework-ios.signature couldn’t be copied to “Signatures” because an item with the same name already exists

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm using MapLibre in React Native project, when i do `bunx eas build --profile preview --local -p ios` i start getting this error, but no issues when doing in simulator.

I did have MapBox in my other project and that is working fine. But unsure if this related. Or is there a signature being stored in system that i need to manually remove?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is an error from Xcode 15, add the next script to your build phases:

```
if [ "$XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR" = "1500" ]; then
  echo "Remove signature files (Xcode 15 workaround)"

  rm "$BUILD_DIR/Release-iphoneos/Mapbox.xcframework-ios.signature"
fi
```

[Issue reference](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12022)

Comment: This works when archiving but was failing when running in debug mode. I used `rm -f` so it doesn't fail when the file/dir is not found (when running in debug)

Comment: You need to check "For install builds only", in order to avoid running in debug mode

Answer (score 1):

If using Xcode 15 or higher, then this script may fix, just add new step to build phase and tick **For install builds only**:

```bash
if [ "$XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR" = "1500" ]; then
  echo "Remove signature files (Xcode 15 workaround)"
  find "$BUILD_DIR/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos" -name "*.signature" -type f | xargs -r rm
fi
```

2 things updated than previous answer:

- ${CONFIGURATION} for dynamic config
- Process won't stop if there's no *.signature files

This update did save my time in some case, and may be your time too.